# UICollectionViewCell remove border when deselected

Tags: ios, objective-c, border, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionView and i am using this code (in a subclass of UICollectionViewCell) to add a border when the cell is selected:

```
- (void)isSelected{
    NSLog(@"selected");
    [self.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:213.0/255.0f green:210.0/255.0f blue:199.0/255.0f alpha:1.0f].CGColor];
    [self.layer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
    [self.layer setCornerRadius:9.5f];
}

- (void)isNotSelected{
    NSLog(@"not selected");
    [self.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor clearColor].CGColor];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

It does work when the cell is selected but id does not work when deselected. 
I can see the logs for both calls.

How can i remove this border ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a sublayer, and removing this on isNotSelected?

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way (the methods are called in the didSelect and didDeselect delegates methods):

```
- (void)isSelected{
    [self.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:213.0/255.0f green:210.0/255.0f blue:199.0/255.0f alpha:1.0f].CGColor];
    [self.layer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
    [self.layer setCornerRadius:9.5f];
}

- (void)isNotSelected{
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [self.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor clearColor].CGColor];
    [self.layer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
    [self.layer setCornerRadius:9.5f];
    [self.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.imgUrl] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder-avatar"]];
}
```

I really have no idea why my first solution is not working...

Comment: Actually, this is not fully working. If a cell is hidden (for scrolling reasons), it could loose its border...